# Output from an ADC is needed to be stored in memory

Tags: fpga, adc

We want to take the output of a 16-bit Analog to Digital Converter, which is coming at a rate of 10 million samples per second and SAVE the sequence of 16 output bits in a computer memory. How to save this 16-bit binary voltage signal (0V, 5V) in a computer memory?
If a FPGA is to be used, please elaborate the method.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Sample Data and feed to fifo
2. Take data from fifo and prepare UDP frames and send data over ethernet
3. Received UDP packets on PC side and put in memory